# Is there a %config(noreplace) option for setup.py's bdist_rpm?

Tags: python-2.7, rpm, setuptools

I am building a python package, and I want to distribute it via rpm using `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. However, I am including a configuration file, and I want any changes in there to remain if I ever upgrade the RPM on the machine it's installed on. Is there anyway to set a flag in the setup.py script or command that I don't want the RPM to replace the configuration file in case of upgrades? I'm on Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
python setup.py  bdist_rpm --spec-only
```

This will create dist/*.spec, manually edit it. Especially change:

```
%install
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES
    
%files -f INSTALLED_FILES
```

to:

```
%install
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
    
%files
%{python_sitelib}/*
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/yourconfig.conf
```

Note: you may add more lines to %files section, it depends what you put in buildroot. If you miss something rpmbuild from next step will report it as error.

Then you can build the SRPM using

```
rpmbuild -bs dist/*.spec
```

More resources can be found here:

[https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/)

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package